# buildVectorS function has error

Tags: c++

I got error the below code, please let me know what I did wrong. Thank you. Kelly
I not sure what I did wrong with buildVectorS function. please let me know what is wrong

after I click "compile and run"--> box pop up with Enter names: --> I type name Adams
after then, I see the small box appear with the below comment

> untitled12.exe has stopped working
>   a problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
>   windows will close the program and notify you
>   if a solution is available"`

```
Enter names:
adams

Thank you.

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

void buildVectorS(vector<string> &vect, int numItems){
     cout << "Enter names : " << endl;
     string tmp;
     for(int i = 0; i <=numItems; i++)
        cin >> tmp; 
        vect.push_back(tmp);

      //for(int i = 0; i <= numItems; i++)
      //   vect.push_back(vect[i]);   
}

void displayVectorS(vector<string> vect){
  for(int i = 0; i <vect.size(); i++)
     cout << vect[i] << " " <<endl;
}

int main(){   
    vector<string> names; 
    buildVectorS(names,5);
    displayVectorS(names);
    cout << endl;

    sort(names.begin(), names.end());
    displayVectorS(names);
    cout << endl;  

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I think you meant `names` where you are using `numbers`. Isn't it ?

Comment: use std::vector.reserve(numItems) (which should be unsigned) - check the stream if(cin) { ... } else error(); - pass const std::vector& to displayVectorS - and the post of Andrew_CS

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector named names and then attempt to pass in numbers which isn't anything.

```
int main(){
    vector<string> names; 
    buildVectorS(numbers,10)

    ..........
```

Change all of the numbers to names.

Also now that you've edited the question this code seems to work.

```
void buildVectorS(vector<string> &vect, int numItems){
    cout << "Enter names : " << endl;
    string tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i <=numItems; i++){
       cin >> tmp;
       vect.push_back(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt respone.

Comment: Make sure you take a look at my edited answer, it covers the new errors you were getting.

Comment: void buildVectorS(vector<string> &vect, int numItems){
     cout << "Enter names : " << endl;
     string tmp;
     for(int i = 0; i <=numItems; i++)
        cin >> tmp; 
        vect.push_back(tmp);

Comment: Enter names :
Laula
Cathy
Smith
Adams
Cynthia
Mark
Mark

Mark

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You're missing the brackets around the for loop.